# Batch script to start another bat file with a timeout for execution

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to to Call a bat file then waiting for an expected execution time
and then act on the execution result of the second batch file , It will be like .
1- First Batch file "Main_file.bat"

```
@ECHO OFF
CALL Second_file.bat
echo LEVEL = %ERRORLEVEL% 
ping -n 5 localhost >nul 
echo LEVEL = %ERRORLEVEL% 
IF [%ERRORLEVEL%] == [5] (
 taskkill /IM "app.exe" /F
)
```

2- "Second_file.bat"

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO -------START-----------
python CI_prallel_d.py CDPO_L2_INT Setter
::Set ERORRLEVEL
exit /b 5
```

I want to Know how to Ignore the exit code for ping command and act on the exit code of my second_file.bat is there a way ?

Comment: Store the value of `%ErrorLevel%` in a variable…

Answer (score 0):

```
start ping -n 5 localhost >nul
```